# How to set a home directory limit for all users in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to set home directory limit of 10GB for all users in Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how could I do that?

Answer (score 5):

For clarification, do you want your home directory in total to have a 10GB limit? Or do you require each user individually to have a 10G limit for their respective home directories?

Some how-to's which should help you with both scenarios:

Debian, quick rundown:
http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-journaled-quota-on-debian-lenny

Centos based, but thorough clear and easy to follow
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-disk-quotas.html

Comment: I want to set a 10GB limit for individual user in Ubuntu.

Comment: Charly,

The tutorials/docs I listed are what you are looking to follow. 

To sum up the process to set user quotas:

1. In your /etc/fstab, add "usrquota,grpquota" to the options for the partition you are looking to enable quota on.
2. Create the quota files by: 
# touch /aquota.user && touch /aquota.group && chmod 600 /aquota.*
3. Remount your file system with new options:
# mount -o remount / (partition modified in fstab)
4. Turn on quotas
# quotaon -av
5. Edit individual quotas with the 'edquota' command. You will be editing the 'soft' and 'hard' limits ( 10240000 will be 10gb)

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html) for setting up user and group quotas on Linux.